# How to transfer base64 image from client to server or download binary / base64 from s3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, twitter, base64, multipartform-data

In my app, i'm sending photos directly from the client to s3, using something similar to this suggested heroku recommendation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

The main benefit is that it saves server cost (i'm assuming since chunks aren't being sent to the server using something such as multipart-y form data).

However, I wish to be able to share these images to twitter also, which states this requirement:

> Ensure the POST is a multipart/form-data request. Either upload the raw binary (media parameter) of the file, or its base64-encoded contents (media_data parameter). Use raw binary when possible, because base64 encoding results in larger file sizes

*I've tried sending the base64 needed for the client-side s3 upload back to the server, but depending on the photo size -- I often get an error that it's too big to send back.*

**TLDR**

Do I need to send my photos using mulitparty / multipart form data to my server, so I can have the needed base64 / binary to share a photo to twitter, or can I keep sending photos from my client to s3?

Then, somehow, ***efficiently*** obtain the needed base64 / binary on the server (possibly using the request module), so I can then send the image to twitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly easy way to do this without changing your client code a whole lot would be to use [S3 events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html). S3 events can trigger a lambda function in AWS that can post the image to twitter. You can use any library inside the lambda function to do efficient posting to twitter. Not sure if you want to use Lambda or stick to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly uploading documents from the client to upload to s3, you are exposing your AWS secret/private keys with the client. A more secure way would be uploading the images to node and node in turn upload it to S3. A recommended way to upload images to node server would be using 
multipart/form-data and using [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware.

Regardless of the upload method, you can use the following code to serve images to twitter. This code uses *AWS-SDK* module.

```
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var filename = req.query.filename;
    var params = {
        Bucket: <bucketname>,
        Key: <image path>
    };

    var extension = filename.split('.')[1];
    if (extension == "jpg" || extension == "JPG" || extension == "jpeg" || extension == "JPEG")
    {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image');
    }
    else if (extension == "png" || extension == "PNG")
    {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    }

    s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(res);
```

This method can scale with easy like any other express app.

Comment: You do not need to expose your AWS credentials to allow end users to upload directly to S3.  Look up "Uploading Objects Using Pre-Signed URLs"

Comment: Yes, my credentials are secured on the server.